# Access denied for user anonymous for node retrieve service

Tags: 7, services

I have installed services module and added a service. And then, enabled the retrieve and index resources for node. I also enabled the permission to view the published content for anonymous users. cache is also cleared. When i call the retrieve or index service, i am getting the below response.

> http://example.com/endpoint/node/1.json

Response:

`["Access denied for user anonymous"]`

Is there any thing i missed here?

Version D7 - Services 7.x-3.20

Update:
It was issue with domain module. Domain strict module was enabled. After disabling, it started working.

Comment: Did you enable `Session authentication` under `/admin/structure/services/list/[my-endpoint-name]`?

Comment: Yes, session authentication is enable. But i found that the issue is with domain strict module which was enable in my site. I updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was issue with domain module. Domain strict module was enabled. After disabling, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure node/1 status must be published, otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: Yes, it is published node.

Comment: I had simply installed the module and after end point creation enabled the node indexing and retrieving. It works fine without any issue.